# Calling an existing worksheet with vba by using its code name in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the formula of a cell to an if formula that uses data from an already existing sheet within the workbook.  However whenever trying to reference the sheet i get a file dialog box that opens looking for the path for the sheet. Below you will find my code which loops through all existing sheets in the workbook and compares it to a sheet name when it finds a match it stores the sheet code name for the current and previous weeks.  Once it has these I have an if statement that tries to access these sheets and compare values.  It is at this point that I get the file dialog box.  Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you. Sorry for formatting issues I will correct as soon as possible.

```
sheetName = CStr(Year(Now)) & " eDR FW" & CStr(Format(Date, "ww")) & "_2"

lastWeekName = CStr(Year(Now)) & " eDR FW" & CStr(Format(Date, "ww") - 1) & "_2"

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    If ws.Name = sheetName Then

        sheetName = ws.CodeName

    ElseIf ws.Name = lastWeekName Then

        lastWeekName = ws.CodeName

    End If

Next

rowRange = colLetter & "2:" & colLetter & CStr(sheetRowCount)

lineofBalance = "=IFERROR(IF(INDEX('" & lastWeekName & "'!$A$2:$W$10000,MATCH(A2,'" & sheetName & "'!$A$2:$A$10000,0),6)=F2,F2,CONCATENATE(""Updated: ""&F2)),CONCATENATE(""New: ""&F2))"
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you get the prompt in the IF block? What line exactly? Have you declared your variables?

Comment: I've never used the sheet's codename before, but it seems to remain the same. It keeps "Sheet1" as the codename for the default first worksheeet of a new workbook... Even after the sheet was renamed and the workbook was closed and re-opened. Therefore, it seems unreliable to me... Maybe you meant to use the `.Name` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do to make this work is change both `ws.Codename` to `ws.Name`.

The `.Codename` property only contains the first name of the sheet when it was originally created (which is most likely something like "Sheet32") and not the current name of the worksheet. It *CAN* be changed but most likely will remain the same unless you REALLY intend to change it. The formula with the erroneous worksheet name then opens the dialog box to try to find a reference for that particular worksheet.

Excel's formulas are designed to work with the **current worksheet name** and not it's **codename**. The only useful way I can see of using the `.Codename`, is if you wanna make sure to always use a particular worksheet (within VBA) even if the name of the worksheet was changed at some point (by yourself or a user).

Comment: Thank you I will try as soon as I get a chance and vote appropriately.

Comment: Hello, while using this I am able to get the f function to work it still creates a dialog box when run before getting to the if statement right before the if statement is called.  I have to cancel the dialog box before the statement completes.

Comment: Are you sure there is no erroneous function somewhere in the sheet?

Comment: I do not believe so as I ended up turning the alarm off for that section of code and got everything to calculate correctly based on all of my test data and checks.